# Xbox360 headphone says I'm talking but no one can hear me

Tags: xbox-360

I have had this mic for a year now and just yesterday it stopped working. The Icon that a mic is plugged in is showing up, and when I talk the waves show up no one can hear me. Please help because I don't want to have to buy a new mic just to find out i could have easily fixed it. Btw I'm using a turtle beach earforce xl1

Comment: Have you tried using another mic?  The problem could be any number of things.  You need to narrow it down and isolate what's causing the problem.  Try using a different mic, a different cord connecting the mic to the controller, etc. until you find the point of failure

Comment: Not exactly familiar with 360 settings, but double check your accessory output volume and make sure it isn't too low. (which would explain why it picks up, but doesn't output to anyone, at least noticably..)

Comment: Can this headset be used with a PC? If so, can you test it using a PC's sound recorder?

Comment: I will try that dangerzone and no studoku it can't.